# Get only users posts from facebook graph for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, graph

Does anybody know if it is possible to fectch the data only from one user his posts on the wall.

For instance:
If i want to get the Nike feed i do this:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"nike/feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

But this gives me al the posting on the Nike facebook wall, but i actually only need Nike's own posts like this: http://www.facebook.com/nike?sk=wall&filter=2

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do the following request "nike/posts". According to the [Facebook Developper Page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) it will display the Page's own posts.

Cheers.

Comment: Oops didn't found that page before... But it works! Thank man